Particular Polynomial Vanishing Mod p
Suppose that $q$ is a prime power, and let $\mathbb{F}$ be the field with $q^2$ elements.
Suppose that

$i,j \in \mathbb{Z} / (q^2 - 1)\mathbb{Z}$
$(q-1) \mid (i-j),$
$(q+1) \nmid i,j$.

Then I am trying to show that if
$$
\alpha^i + \alpha^{qi} = \alpha^j + \alpha^{qj}
$$
for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$, then either $i = j$ or $i = qj$ (in $\mathbb{Z} / (q^2 - 1)\mathbb{Z}$).
I have checked computationally and this is true when $q$ is a prime smaller than 50.

Ideas:

Rearranging, $(\alpha^i - \alpha^j)^q = - (\alpha^i - \alpha^j)$, and so when $\alpha \neq 0$, $y = \alpha^i - \alpha^j$ satisfies $y^{q-1} = -1$. However, I can't yet seem to be able to use this to say anything useful.

Using the answer to this question, we must have that
$$
X^{q^2} - X \mid (X^i - X^j)^q + (X^i - X^j)
$$
in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}[X]$. Then maybe one can use this to obtain relations between $i$ and $j$. However, it seemed to get messy quite quickly.


Any ideas or suggestions appreciated!

Try to show that the polynomial $F:=(x^i-x^j)^q+(x^i-x^j)$ is the map $\alpha\mapsto 0$ on $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ if and only if $i=j$ or $i=qj$. You can do so by considering $F$ as a composition of $x^q+x$ and $x^i-x^j$. What are the roots of $x^q+x$? This should give you a lead.

It may not be relevant but I guessed you already used the fact that $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^\times \simeq \mathbb{Z} / (q^2-1)\mathbb{Z}$?

@schiepy OK - how does this point of view make things easier?

@julio_es_sui_glace yes, thanks, that's actually where $\mathbb{Z} / (q^2 - 1) \mathbb{Z}$ comes from in the first place in the formulation I gave above.

@schiepy Considering $F$ as a composition like this is essentially the same as what I described in idea 1 above, but I couldn't see that this goes anywhere useful.

Yeah I thought so but just in case ;)

Yeah, my comment was kinda useless I guess, sorry. If $q$ is odd, the polynomial $x^q+x$ has exactly the set of square-roots of the non-squares in $\mathbb{F}q$ as roots (which are in $\mathbb{F}{q^2})$ and I thought that can be exploited somehow. However, after thinking about it myself a bit more I also couldn't make it work.

Here's one way.
The case $\alpha=0$ is not interesting for the purposes of your condition, so assume $\alpha\neq0$. Consider the polynomial
$$
p_{i,\alpha}(T)=(T-\alpha^i)(T-\alpha^{qi})\in\Bbb{F}[T].
$$
By expanding, we arrive at
$$p_{i,\alpha}(T)=T^2-(\alpha^i+\alpha^{qi})T+\alpha^{(q+1)i}.\tag{1}$$
As we are assuming that $(q-1)\mid (i-j)$, it follows that
$$
q^2-1=(q-1)(q+1)\mid (q+1)(i-j)
$$
and therefore
$$(q+1)i\equiv (q+1)j\pmod{q^2-1}.\tag{2}$$
As $\alpha^{q^2-1}=1$ the congruence $(2)$ implies that
$$
\alpha^{(q+1)i}=\alpha^{(q+1)j}.\tag{3}
$$
Together with the assumption $\alpha^i+\alpha^{qi}=\alpha^j+\alpha^{qj}$ items $(1)$ and $(3)$ imply that
$$
p_{i,\alpha}(T)=p_{j,\alpha}(T).
$$
Therefore the sets of zeros of $p_{i,\alpha}$ and $p_{j,\alpha}$ must coincide. That is,
$$\{\alpha^i,\alpha^{qi}\}=\{\alpha^j,\alpha^{qj}\}.\tag{4}$$
In particular, $\alpha^j$ must be one of the elements $\alpha^i$ or $\alpha^{qi}$.
If we choose $\alpha$ to be a primitive element (= a generator of the cyclic group $\Bbb{F}^*$), then the powers of $\alpha$ repeat periodically with period exactly $q^2-1$ but are otherwise distinct. Therefore either $j\equiv i$ or $j\equiv qi$.

that's a beautiful proof, thank you very much!

The strong assumption $(q-1)\mid (i-j)$ means that it suffices for your condition to hold for a single choice of $\alpha$ as long as it is a primitive element.

yes, the whole difficulty I had was trying to "split things up", and get rid of the addition, with a view towards using a primitive element! Thanks again.
